# Workflow: C pointer to Python array?

Tags: python, c, cython

I am writing some code in C, which reads data in and stores it in a pointer of type;

`uint8_t`

This data I now want to make accessible in Python3.

For now I have figured out how to make my C code callable with the help of ctypes and I know it works since I am able to print my data out in the Python terminal, but not able to store it in a variable.

My problem lies in that I do not know how to transform this pointer into an array which can be stored and manipulated in Python, so therefore I ask, if someone has a simple example where they move for an example a 3 by 1 array from C into Python, and then are able to work with it there, it would benefit me a lot.

Comment: This is either a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628337/using-array-array-in-python-ctypes or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584439/passing-memoryview-to-c-function depending on what you're using to wrap your C code (your question and tags tell me different things).

Comment: Thanks, still new to C, so I really struggle at looking at others code right now, but managed to find a solution my self. Thanks, for commenting

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed to figure it out, maybe not the smartest way, but atleast it works now. Since I return a pointer of the type, ``` u_int8 * ```` in C, I amble then in Python to use something like this:

```
g = (ctypes.c_float*5271).from_address(a)
```

And then g[0], g[:], etc. to get the data etc.